# Calling Slider Revolution assets through relative paths on Rails 4 App

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, revolution-slider

**question reworked for clarity and brevity**

I am trying to install the [Slider Revolution][1] plugin on my Rails 4 application and I am having trouble with dynamically created relative paths in the jquery.themepunch.revolution.js file.   The javascript snippet that I've placed on the page (as per the docs) sets a parent directory via this code:

```
 jsFileLocation:"../../revolution/js/",
```

This directory tells the code in **jquery.themepunch.revolution.js**  where to find the "extensions" folder.

But, if I use that bit of js on my page I get this error

```
Slider Revolution 5.0 Error !
Failure at Loading:revolution.extension.navigation.min.js on Path:extensions/
```

as the js is telling the browser to search HERE for the file:

```
http://localhost:5000/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js
```

when in reality the actual location is something like:

```
http://localhost:5000/assets/javascripts/plugins/revolution/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js
```

I've tried setting the js snippet to the following options:

```
jsFileLocation:"../../assets/",
jsFileLocation:"../../assets/javascripts/",
jsFileLocation:"/assets/",
jsFileLocation:"/assets/javascripts/plugins/revolution/",
jsFileLocation:"/assets/plugins/revolution/",
```

It still doesn't work.

Comment: Got a repo that could be cloned and investigated?

Comment: Added the link to the repo

Comment: @N can you check that your repo is a runnable copy of your project as I'm unable to get this project to run without a tonne of errors :/ - as it is, I'm going to find it hard to know where to begin. At least 20 missing images and a blank white page

Comment: oof.  Sorry. The blank white page is the error and occurs with/without the image 404s...I've fixed the image 404s so they won't distract.  Sorry to not clean house before inviting you.

Comment: Ah sorry. It was late when I first looked into this and hadn't bothered to re-read the question as I was expecting something more than what we're getting - so it does indeed reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `/assets/plugins/revolution/` as the js location. I am assuming you haven't tried it.

Comment: jsFileLocation:"/assets/revolution/", did not work.  however jsFileLocation:"/assets/plugins/revolution/", did ..thought I thought I had tried that. Can you update your answer to say "/assets/plugins/revolution/" and I'll give you the bounty?